# 100vh does not apply when switching dynamic react components

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react app with a form that is dynamic. Every time the form changes the side bar which is set to 100vh doesn't cover the full page.

[image]

The CSS for the sidebar is as follows:

```
border-right: 1px solid rgb(233, 236, 239);
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 100vh !important;
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 side-bar" style="width: 280px">
        <!-- side bar content -->
    </div>
    <div class="app-content-inner">
        <!-- dynamic content rendered here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I make sure the sidebar is covering 100% of the page and change when the component changes?

Comment: Please add some rendered HTML in a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: Are there any other CSS rules positioning that element?  It may be that it's 100% of viewport height, but its top is offscreen.  (There's not nearly enough code here to be sure, but your use of `!important` suggests this is a possibility, if you're in the habit of needing to brute-force the cascade like that then your rules are probably too broad and affecting things they shouldn't)

Comment: @DanielBeck dev tools shows it's just underneath the Navigation bar. There shouldn't be any other positioning rules other then bootstrap flex stuff. the !important was left over from trying stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS `max-height: 100vh`  was not covering the full page. Changed this to:

```
 min-height: 100vh
```

Now the side bar covers the whole page regardless of the size of the content.